# Rails copy data from one form to another

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a search box which searches records for `guests`.  If zero results come up, I have a button that appears to take users to the `guests/new` page, where the same parameters of the search are found for users to input to create a new record.  Is it possible to copy the data from the search box and fill the new guest form automatically with it?

Search box:

```
<%= form_tag(guests_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
          <div class="input-append col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_first_name, params[:search_first_name], placeholder: "First Name", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_last_name, params[:search_last_name], placeholder: "Last Name", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_email, params[:search_email], placeholder: "Email Address", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
              <p><%= text_field_tag :search_phone, params[:search_phone], placeholder: "Phone Number", style: "width:100%;" %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
              <%= submit_tag 'Search Guests' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

New guest form (guests/_form.html.erb included on page guests/new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for(@guest) do |f| %>
  <% if @guest.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@guest.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this guest from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @guest.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :phone %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form you should be able to set a default value based on what it's passed in in the query-string as params. This is a example that you can replicate all over the form.

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :value => params[:first_name] if params[:acction] == 'new' %>
```

I hope that this helps

Happy Hacking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it. It should take little more time.

You have to use JS or JQuery.

```
$('button').click(function(){
var text = $('input[id="search"]').val();
$('input[id="guest"]').val(text);
console.log(text);
})
```

I have made little example in this link: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af1bL5za/)

Comment: This does not seem to be working and carrying over properly because my form tags dont match the new form tags

Comment: Output of this in html 

`<%= text_field_tag :search_first_name, params[:search_first_name] %>` 
should be like this `<input type="text" name="search_first_name">`

Comment: the js isn't working for some reason across the page reload

Comment: @DanBrookwell Ohh, I think u passing `redirect_to` in a controller try to use `render :back`. When using `redirect_to` it refreshes the page, but `render` doesnt. Another case you do it **Async**. If you know to use `:remote => true` in a form...

Comment: @DanBrookwell check your github and pull that request, its in guest-page branch !!!